# Calling function os.popen() gives unexpected return object

Tags: python-2.x

I am using *os.popen()* to call some argument. When I call the argument itself in terminal it works perfectly and I get the expected return object. But when I call it using the *os.popen()* I get

> os._wrap_close object at 0x7f6ec0d3d1d0>

Code:

```
    > command = "python -m json.tool \"" + path + video +"-something.json\"| grep \"ext\\\"\"  
    > result = os.popen(command) 
    > print(result)
```

I find it confusing to get different results, when it should be the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command opens a pipe to the command (stdout, with popen2/3/4 stdin, stderr) and returns an open file object and not the stdout of the command. ([python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen))
So in order to get the result of your command you have to read the open file which can be done with `result.read()`.

[Here](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-os-and-subprocess-popen-commands/) is a nice explanation on the different popen and their (basic) usage.